# How to make wrapper's constructors copy paste the underlying type's constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, wrapper

I am writing a class `stalker<Obj>` that holds inside a variable of type `Obj`. I want `stalker<Obj>` to pretend that it is the same as `Obj` (from the user's perspective). Thus, I expect that `stalker<Obj>` is constructible like `Obj`.

```
template <typename Obj>
class stalker {
  Obj obj;
  // other variables

 public:
  template <typename... Args>
  stalker(Args&&... args) : obj(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
  }
};
```

I implement only copy & move constructors additionally.

`stalker<Obj>` also has other variable(s) which require some specific logiс (independent from `Obj`) when created.

`Obj` can be marked `final`.

However, my approach fails on distinguishing `std::initialiser_list` and curly brackets object. The compiler says: *"No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<int>'"*.

```
int main() {
  stalker<std::vector<int>> v = {1, 2, 3};  // CE
  stalker<std::vector<int>> v({1, 2, 3});   // CE

  return 0;
}
```

How to reach `stalker<Obj>` maximal imitation of `Obj` in terms of construction?

Creating constructors from `const Obj&` and `Obj&&` fails: sometimes the compiler cannot conclude which of these constructors fits the best and in other cases it does not try to adapt `{...} -> std::init_list -> Obj` at all (just `{...} -> Obj`).

I added these constructors (is `std::is_constructible` enough?):

```
 template <typename T>
 requires (std::is_constructible_v<Obj, const std::initializer_list<T>&>)
 stalker(const std::initializer_list<T>& init_list) : obj(init_list) {
 }

 template <typename T>
 requires (std::is_constructible_v<Obj, std::initializer_list<T>&&>)
 stalker(std::initializer_list<T>&& init_list) : obj(std::move(init_list)) {
 }
```

However, now it compiles with `std::vector` but shows an error (and it does work with the raised error after all!):

```
struct A {
  int val;
};

int main() {
  stalker<A> a = {1};

  return 0;
}
```

Also, it does not convert inner `{...}` to `std::initialiser_list`.

```
int main() {
  stalker<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                                              {5, 6, 7},
                                              {8, 9},
                                              {10}};

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you conditionally `enable_if` have a stalker constructor that forwards the initializer list if the underlying `Obj` has a constructor for an initializer list?

Comment: And a user could have ment to create some instance of object by {...} and pass it via `Obj&&`

Comment: "*I want `stalker<Obj>` to pretend that it is the same as `Obj` (from the user's perspective)*" - then, why not simply *derive* `stalker` from `Obj` so that `stalker` IS an `Obj`? `template <typename Obj> class stalker : public Obj { // other variables ... public: using Obj::Obj; };`

Comment: `Obj` can be marked `final`

Comment: Stack Overflow Usage note: [Don't use images of code, diagnostic messages, or anything else that's text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301)

Comment: The reason it "doesn't work" on `struct A` is because it's not a constructor, but an [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: @Vivick but why it shows an error?

Comment: Because you're trying to use aggregate initialization on something that's not an aggregate

Comment: To make `vector<vector<>>` case work ,you'd need a constructor declared as `stalker(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>)`, so that the inner type can be be inferred from the aggregate list.  Without it, the compiler won't make up anything. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: `std::initializer_list<T>` can match `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<?>>` where `T = std::initializer_list<?>>` so adding your suggestion would just make it redundant

Comment: @Vivick I think the problem is that the compiler highly likely cannot deduce the type of a nested curly bracket object at all like in our case where it is supposed to be `std::initialiser_list<int>`. It just shows that he sees some argument `{...}`

Comment: It doesn't work even with the nested `std::initialiser_list` (says the constructor call takes multiple arguments instead of 1). I also tried a variadic set of `std::initializer_list` to remedy that, but that couldn't get deduced either